# finding index of greatest element comparison in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have an array `a` and I want to find the position of largest element in `a` that a given value is still greater than.

In this example:

```
a = np.array([0, 50, 5, 52, 60])
v = 55
```

the greatest element that `v` is bigger than is `52` (index 3) so I want to return 3.

The numpy function `argmax()` doesn't work for this purpose since it returns the first element. What is the fast and correct way to do this with numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice the array and find the maximum yourself and then query its index:

```
np.where(a==a[a<v].max())
Out: (array([3]),)
```

Comment: this assumes there is such an element in ``a`` - it fails otherwise

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `argmax` with `where`:

```
>>> np.nanargmax(np.where(a < v, a, np.nan))
3
```

The `np.where` replaces all values above `v` to `nan` before it applies `nanargmax` (which ignores `nan`s in the computation):

```
>>> np.where(a < v, a, np.nan)
array([  0.,  50.,   5.,  52.,  nan])
```

Comment: I was also looking for ways to set those values to something else and found that argmax is also defined on masked arrays. So it seems like it would work with `np.ma.masked_array(a, a>=v).argmax()` too but I am not sure as I didn't work with masked arrays before.

Comment: Yes, `masked_arrays` should also work. I probably would have used `np.ma.masked_greater_equal(a, v).argmax()`. But a fast way was asked and in my experience masked arrays generally perform worse.